# Putting commas in amount field in Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a MVC app. I have some amount fields. by default it showing numbers without comma separation. for e.g. if I have amount 500000000 then I want to display it like 50,00,00,000 I want to show in Indian currency format,in indian format first comma comes after 3 digits then for every 2 digits comma appears.

How to do this ?

I have tried this , but giving an error...

```
  @{  

 System.Globalization.CultureInfo Indian = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
  }
                       @(String.Format(Indian, "{0:N}", modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount))
    }
```

> Solved, Thanks to Darin Dimitrov, Answer Is :

```
@{
    var indianCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    @string.Format(indianCulture, "{0:N}", item.SanctionedAmount)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have passed some lambda expression to the `string.Format` function (`modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount`), but this function doesn't take any delegates.

Try like this:

```
@{
    var indianCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    @string.Format(indianCulture, "{0:N}", item.SanctionedAmount)
}
```

Comment: @user1650894, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer.

Comment: Well, Darin my problem is solved almost everywhere, just remained at only one line of code I stuck... I want to use this format in label. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In the same context the following also works if you put in `Index.cshtml`

`<td>@item.Total_Payments.ToString("N")</td>`

Answer (score 0):

//In the same context the following also works if you put in
@item.SanctionedAmount.ToString("#,##0.00")